# NSPredicate get entities with attribute not in a given array

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, nspredicate, cloudkit

I am using CloudKit to store and sync some data in my app. Let's say I have a record type with an attribute named `key`. I want to fetch all records with `key` not in a given array `unwantedKeyArray`.

I tried

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "key NOT IN %@", unwantedKeyArray)
```

But the app crashed with error saying

> 'Unable to parse the format string "key NOT IN %@"'

So what's the correct way to create a `NSPredicate` to achieve my goal?

(Although I use Swift in my app and in this question description, answers in ObjC are also welcome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code example :

```
   NSPredicate(format: "NOT (key IN %@)", unwantedKeyArray)
```